# C++ list remove element from position and place at end

Tags: c++, list, c++11

What is the best way to remove an element from std::list in c++ and place it at the end given an iterator to the current element and the list of course.

This is what I have written now and I am not sure is the best/ correct way of doing it:

```
void MyClass::update(std::list<T> * memSegs, std::list<T>::iterator it){

    memSegs -> splice(
        memSegs -> end(),
        *memSegs,
        it
    );
}
```

Comment: Define *best*. Why not just `push_back(*it); erase(it)`?

Comment: I guess simplest is what I mean and maybe constant time...

Comment: @NiklasB.: Ew, that copies the element, which is definitly unnecessary, as only the node needs to be moved. I think OP's code is perfectly correct.

Comment: @Saher: So what's the problem with your approach?

Comment: Is it the good? Is what Niklas proposed better?

Comment: If you pass the list by pointer rather than a reference you have to worry about if it's null.   Try

`    void MyClass::update(std::list<T> & memSegs, std::list<T>::iterator it)`

instead.

Comment: @Xeo: Agreed on that part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do *not* care about the order of the other elements then the simplest solution is just to swap the element pointed to by `it` with the last element in the container.

```
std::swap(*it, memSegs->back());
```

Otherwise [`std::list::splice`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/splice) indeed seems to be the best choice.

For other containers as e.g. `std::vector`, and if you want to maintain order (swap if you don't care), then you can use [`std::rotate`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/rotate) which has linear complexity.

```
std::rotate(it, std::next(it), std::end(*memSegs));
```

Comment: nice idea +1. unfortunately, I care about the order. This is for an eviction policy I am implementing where the last element in the least recently used.

Answer (score 1):

From what the cppreference tells me, This indeed seems optimal. Constant time, element is moved.